# Spring Cloud Contract does not work with Surefire 2.20

Tags: spring-cloud, maven-surefire-plugin, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying Spring Cloud Contact: I have an endpoint "/greeting" in my spring-boot application, and it returns "Hello World!".

The contract is like below:

```
request { 
    method 'GET' 
    url '/greeting' 
    headers { 
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
response { 
    status 200 
    body([ 
           "content": "Hello, World!"
    ])
}
```

My test class:

```
public class ExampleJavaConsumerPactTestIT {

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new GreetingController());
}

@Test
public void aQuickTest(){
}
```

}

Everything works fine: if I change the above contract to "content": "Hello!", then the test fails.

However, when I add in my dependency to user Surefire plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then I run the test again with the wrong contract(content": "Hello!"), the test should fail but it does not.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Can you post your sample somewhere? It will be difficult to help you without this...

Comment: Is ExampleJavaConsumerPactTestIT your verifier base class?
Otherwise <include>**/*IT.java</include> might not include it.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I put my source here https://github.com/pkid/spring-cloud-contract-with-surefire. Basically I am expecting a build failure if I do "mvn clean test -Pcontract-tests"

Comment: @Jeff Yes, I have set baseClassForTests. You can take a look at github.com/pkid/spring-cloud-contract-with-surefire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is wrong. The generated test is called `ContractVerifierTest` so it's not picked by either of your profiles. Just add the `<include>**/*ContractVerifierTest.java</include>` line to your surefire configuration.